# does epsilon-delta definition of limit presuppose that the function is defined everywhere at (x-delta,x+delta)?

Tags: calculus, limits

definition of limit says that we can choose a delta etc... f(x)-Limit is smaller than epsilon. but the notation f(x) presuposses that f is defined at x.

so does definition say we can find delta where the function defined everywhere at (x-delta, x+delta) such that f(x)-Limit is smaller than epsilon  or we can find delta if f(x) defined then f(x)-Limit is smaller than epsilon

what is the difference? according to one we also must show that the chosen delta deliniates a interval where f(x) is defined

and according to other we should only care about the cases where it is defined.

Comment: It is tacitly understood that only points $x$ in the domain of $f$ have to pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't: you have the property in the intersection of the interval of radius $\delta$ around $x$ with the domain of the function. This might not be the entire interval. For example, a function defined on $[0,1]$ can be continuous at $0$, in which case the relevant interval is $[0,\delta)$.

Comment: is f defined for everypoint in the relevant interval [0,delta)?

Comment: @user249722 In my example, yes, although that's not necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

**Does epsilon-delta definition of limit presuppose that the function is defined everywhere at $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$?**

Not. The definition only presuppose that, for each $\delta>0$, the function is defined at least in a point of the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

More precisely, in the context of real functions of real variables, the definition of
$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$$
presuppose that, for every $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in \operatorname{Dom}(f)\cap(c-\delta ,c+\delta)$. In other words, this definition presuppose
$$\operatorname{Dom}(f)\cap(c-\delta ,c+\delta)\neq \varnothing,\quad\forall\ \delta>0.$$

It means that $c$ has to be a *limit point* of $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$. In general, in the context of Calculus, this condition is automatically satisfied so that you don't have to worry about it.

**So does definition say we can find delta where the function defined everywhere at (x-delta, x+delta) such that f(x)-Limit is smaller than epsilon or we can find delta if f(x) defined then f(x)-Limit is smaller than epsilon**

Your second possibility is correct: you have to find a $\delta$ such that: **if** $f(x)$ is defined (that is, if $x\in \operatorname{Dom}(f)\cap(c-\delta,c+\delta)$), then f(x)-Limit is smaller than epsilon. You don't have to care about the points where the function is undefined.

Comment: I believe your exlanation does not work consider the following function f(x)= 2 if  -1<x<1 undefined otherwise.now i claim that limx-0 f(x)=5 for all epsilon choose delta to be 1/2. since there is no x such that x is a member of(-1/2,1/2) so if f(x) is defined f(x)-L is smaller then epsilon vacously. and the same proof works for the claim that lim= 2 so lim is ambigous, which we know that it is not.

Comment: @user249722 Since your function is defined on $(-1,1)$, why "there is no $x$ such that $x$ is a member of $(-1/2,1/2)$"?

Comment: it is defined everywhere other than (-1,1) and its value is constant 2